# Prerequisites to begin Beauville's "Complex Algebraic Surfaces"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, book-recommendation

I'm going to read through the first three chapters of Arnaud Beauville's *Complex Algebraic Surfaces*. My background in algebraic geometry only consists of Gathmann's algebraic geometry notes (the part before schemes are introduced), but the point of view is quite different: Gathmann is more on the algebraic side, oriented towards schemes; instead Beauville has a more classical point of view, coming from complex geometry. For example, I don't know about complex manifolds, divisors, singularities, which seem to be prerequisites for Beauville's book. Is there any introduction to complex geometry / complex surfaces that you would recommend, in order to move on Beauville's book later? Thank you

Comment: As I can recall, it requires some familiarity with sheaf cohomology (or at least, of the structure sheaf and it's twists by divisors). As far as I can remember nearly all the prerequisites are used in the first chapter, so that should give you an idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently organized a reading course on algebraic surfaces using this book. To follow the book, you will probably need to understand some foundational concepts from algebraic/complex geometry:

1. line bundles, divisors, and their correspondence
2. cohomology of sheaves on algebraic varieties
3. knowledge of the theory of algebraic curves (e.g. Riemann-Roch and Riemann-Hurwitz)
4. at certain points it is also good to know a little bit about manifold topology; e.g. it is good to have some knowledge of singular cohomology and you should know about the exponential exact sequence on a complex manifold

As is sometimes the case in algebraic geometry, the treatment is more in the classical language of varieties and won't test your scheme theory knowledge very often. The best thing to have a handle on here is some basics on complex manifolds (in particular Riemann surfaces) and sheaf cohomology. Pretty much all of the necessary part of the theory related to complex manifolds and sheaf cohomology is in Huybrechts' book *Complex Geometry: An Introduction*. The Riemann surfaces are treated nicely in Miranda's book.

Comment: Nice answer! I assume you mean Huybrecht's _Complex Geometry: An Introduction_ book (instead of "Complex Manifolds").

Comment: Whoops, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Building on the answer of @Alekos Robotis, the background material is covered in the classic *Principles of Algebraic Geometry* by Griffiths and Harris. Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* is an obvious book that one should have some familiarity with. A companion to Beauville's book is the classic *Compact Complex Surfaces* by Barth, Hulek, Peters, and Van de Ven. Sheaf cohomology is nicely treated in *Analytic Functions of Several Complex Variables* by Gunning and Rossi. The theory of algebraic curves and surfaces is also discussed at great length in the Griffiths-Harris book.